# Why powershell Invoke-RestMethod takes so long when requesting localhost?

Tags: powershell

I am doing a localhost request via `irm http://localhost:8080`.
My webserver is super simple and does absolutely nothing, just returns http 200. Powershell is taking 2 seconds to perform this request.

- `curl` took 0.021s
- `irm` took 2.043s

But when performing `irm http://127.0.0.1:8080` it returns in 0.03 seconds, so it is definetly some problem with the `localhost` name

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using curl.exe then `curl` is just a PowerShell alias of `Invoke-WebRequest`. Have you tried turning off progress to see if it affects the results of your test:

```
$ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'http://localhost:8080'
```